# How does Powermockito whenNew work?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

I have tested that incredible feature provided by `whenNew` some days ago, that allows us to "intercept" constructor calls of any class inside tested environment and return eg. mocked instance of given class. I was wondering what are principles behind this? My first thought was a bytecode manipulation in order to inject proper code blocks to contructor but hey - constructors does not return created instance so this is obviously not an answer.

What would it be then? AOP - intercepting contructor calls and replacing it with return given object statements?

Comment: You can do *anything* with bytecode manipulation, so why do you assume constructors not returning a value would present a problem (especially something that would then be solvable by a weaker technique, AOP)?

Comment: @Kayaman so basicly does Powermockito changes bytecode of constructor invocation to return load given object insteed of creating new one via constructor? My experience with bytecode manipulation is basicly none, never had to use it before.

Comment: I don't know the exact steps it does, but the selling point of PowerMock was that it could do things other mocking libraries can't do because it uses bytecode manipulation. There are very few limits once you start changing the bytecode itself.

Comment: After few moments with bytecode viewer I have concluded, that indeed, if we have compiled construction of object with `new Object` into sequence of signature invocation of JVM methods, then there is nothing in the way to change that bytecode block into eg variable assignment insteed of constructor invocation. Magic!

Answer (score 0):

Powermock modifies the bytecode in the *calling* class (the one with `new SomeMockedClass(...)`) so that it recovers and uses the mock instance passed into `whenNew`.

This is not the only way it could be implemented by a mocking library, though. JMockit also mocks constructors, but it does it by modifying the actual constructor instead (which still returns `void`, of course).